# More than one Variable on SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a question about sql developer use. Actually in a query I want to put more than just one value when a press to execute the query. Ex:

```
select * from produto where cd_produto in :cods
```

on :cods I want to put more than one code of product, exemple: 30355,30356

[image: sql dev image]

If I use the query "select * from produto where cd_produto in (30355,30356)" that works fine.

Any sugestions?

Comment: Bind parameters are intended to separate code from data. The use case you ask for would defeat that purpose. You can either add more placeholders or omit them altogether.

Comment: Add another bind variable i.e `(:cd_producto1,:cd_producto2)`

Comment: It works fine because that is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can, but with a little bit more typing. Here's how:

```
select deptno, ename, job
from emp
where job in (select regexp_substr(:par_job, '[^,]+', 1, level)     --> split values
              from dual                                             --> you enter
              connect by level <= regexp_count(:par_job, ',') + 1   --> into rows
             )
order by job;
```

Then:

[image]